# require() a node.js module?

Tags: javascript, node.js, require

I have a node.js module like this:

```
# couchdb.js

var couchdb = {
  // code
}

module.exports = couchdb;
```

How do I do to be able to use require("couchdb") in all my files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your module into folder `~/.node_libraries/` to make it available for all scripts

Comment: This one works, but I made it to a NPM package instead and used "npm link/install".